# Binding events to device context objects in wxpython

Tags: events, wxpython

I am new to wxpython and am running into a problem. What I'd like to do is bind events to device context objects. For example, in one window I would draw a number of different device context objects (i.e. lines, rectangles, etc). First, I would like to be able to select a specific object within the window, for the purposes of linking it to a text box that names it. Second, I'd like to be able to drag the object anywhere within the window, preferably with mouse-down, mouse-move events. I know that this is possible in Tkinter's canvasses, but I can't find any equivalent method in wxpython. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

The wxPython demo has an example of selecting objects and dragging them around. There's also the Whyteboard program that has similar functionality and it's written in wxPython too. I would check that out: https://launchpad.net/whyteboard